# How to set matplotlib axis major ticks with a list of values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some data I want to plot on a log scale, with a specific set of major y-axis ticks

I know I can use something like

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))
```

To specify ticks, but I don't know how to pass an instance of `matplotlib.ticker.Locator` with arbitrary values e.g. if I want to set the ticks to [2,4,100] instead of fixed increments. How do I turn an array of tick values to an object that `set_major_locator` will accept?

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you don't want to just use the call to `yticks`?

```py
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,10,40,50,100]

tick_array = [2, 4, 100] # an array of tick values
plt.scatter(x, y, s=150)
plt.yticks(ticks=tick_array)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Forcing the labels to be what you want by setting the labels of your yticks manually.

```py
# Superscript 0-9
print('\u2070', '\u00b9', '\u00b2', '\u00b3', '\u2074', 
      '\u2075', '\u2076', '\u2077', '\u2078', '\u2079')

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,10,40,1020,50,100]
plt.yscale("log")
tick_array = [2, 4, 100,1000]
labels = [f'{int(x/100)}\u00b3' if x > 999 else # if x is >= 1000 set superscript 3
          f'{int(x/10)}\u00b2' if x > 99 else   # if x is >= 100 set superscript2
          x for x in tick_array]
plt.scatter(x, y, s=150)

plt.yticks(ticks=tick_array, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

```
⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ # Output of the print statement
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get yticks working in conjunction with specifying log scale on the y axis. In particular if I try running exactly the above code but with ```plt.yscale("log")``` as well, the yticks are orders of magnitude

Comment: @KeithWynroe What about `tick_array = np.log10(tick_array)` ??

Comment: So the issue is that regardless of what you specify ```tick_array``` as, ```plt.yscale("log")``` seems to override and use its own major ticks. The above doesn't seem to work for me if I specify a log axis regardless of how I define ```tick_array```, I just get orders of magnitude on the y-axis

Comment: @KeithWynroe would forcing the ytick labels to be what you want by manually setting them work? In the edit, I added a superscript '10' to the ytick labels, you can make any combination of numbers with the unicodes that I provided in the `print()` statement. Then, the variable `labels` is a list made with list comprehension that adds the superscript to the tick_array values.

Comment: @KeithWynroe I even put it in log scale and showed how to include up to the thousands. This can be done as high as you need (10^4, 10^5, etc)